# Bluetooth Ping Latency

Tags: bluetooth, ping, latency, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I am currently working on a project involving a Lego Mindstorms kit. The brick is the NXT and I was curious about the bluetooth ping rates.

I ran a test of 100 pings on it and got some interesting results. The latencies seemed to fall into bands. I increased to 10,000 pings and it highlighted this trend even more clearly. Does anyone know what could cause this to happen?

In case it is relevant, the distance between the sender and receiver was about 3 metres.

[image: 10000 Ping Scatter Plot]

Answer (score 1):

Few reasons :

1. Buffering and internal timers to flush buffers can cause it.
2. Also depends on the ping intervals (i.e. time between subsequent pings), as the link might go to power save mode during inactivity and it will take a fine time to come back up.
3. Size of the ping packets
4. What bluetooth profile is used here ?

Comment: Buffering is my teams guess. It seems that the protocol waits and sends a couple of packets at once. If so how do we revolve that and force it to send one at a time? There is no interval. It just does it as fast as possible. The packet is 4 bytes. I'm not sure what you mean by Bluetooth profile?